# Multiple filter operations via dplyr based on number and type of observations in separate columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the df below, `help.a` and I need to clean this up with multiple filter operations.

```
help.a <- data.frame(id = as.factor(c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "04", "04", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09")),
                     episode = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                     count = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                     var_a = c(73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 43, 43, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 73, 73, 73, 73, 42))


id episode count var_a
01       3     1    73
01       3     2    73
01       3     3    73
01       4     4    73
01       4     5    73
04       3     1    43
04       3     2    43
05       2     1    80
05       2     2    80
05       2     3    80
05       2     4    80
05       3     5    80
09       1     1    73
09       1     2    73
09       1     3    73
09       1     4    73
09       1     5    42
```

**First:** I am trying to remove any ids with a count less than 3 (e.g., id 4)

**Second:** I want to remove observations with multiple episodes *while keeping* the first observed episode (the lowest observed episode number)

**Third:** I want to keep only id observations with the same `var_a` variable... If there are multiple `var_a` observations I want to keep only the first observed variable (e.g., id 9 and var_a 73)

In the end, I am hoping my dataset will look similar to below:

```
id episode count var_a
01       3     1    73
01       3     2    73
01       3     3    73
05       2     1    80
05       2     2    80
05       2     3    80
05       2     4    80
09       1     1    73
09       1     2    73
09       1     3    73
09       1     4    73
```

My attempts thus far have accomplished Part 1 with the below code:

```
help.a %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(!n() <3)
```

Yet, I am stuck with how to tell dplyr to keep first observed `episode` and first observed `var.a` ... Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use all the three conditions in a single `filter` after grouping by 'id'

```
 help.a %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% filter(n() >3 & 
                             episode == first(episode) & 
                             var_a == first(var_a))    
 #       id episode count var_a
#    <fctr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      01       3     1    73
#2      01       3     2    73
#3      01       3     3    73
#4      05       2     1    80
#5      05       2     2    80
#6      05       2     3    80
#7      05       2     4    80
#8      09       1     1    73
#9      09       1     2    73
#10     09       1     3    73
#11     09       1     4    73
```

Comment: Brilliant! Ok just so I am getting this... (1) We can use '&' after filter to add another filter expression... We use that instead of the | or command because we want them to happen in order. (2) Calling `episode == unique(episode)[1]` is calling for the first unique episode, and the index of [1] is saying that. And (3) The same for var_a with using the index of [1] again. Does that sound right?

Comment: @bpace I changed the `unique(episode)[1]` to `first(episode)` to make things faster.  We are using the `&` so that only rows that satisfy all these conditions get filtered in.

Comment: Ah it looks like you changed it to first( ) ... That makes sense. And that must be the same as indexing with [1], correct?

Comment: @bpace Yes, it is much more faster.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, @akrun. Cheers!